# zip file corrupted after uploading to AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I upload my zip simply by Using `boto3` . Everything work fine except when I download the zip from my s3 bucket. When I'm trying to unzip in mac OS I get an `error 22` that let me know the zip cannot be uncompressed. I have no idea what's going wrong.

Current situation :

```
file = request.files["my_zip_file"] # file obj (multipart / form-data)
s3.upload_fileobj(
                        file,
                        BUCKET_NAME,
                        folder_name,
                        ExtraArgs={
                           "ContentEncoding": "base64",
                           "ContentType": file.content_type
                        }
                    )
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What actually is `request.files["my_zip_file"]`? Can you provide complete, reproducable example?

Comment: `request.files["my_zip_file"]` is simply the zipfile that is uploaded from a browser

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what are you doing. If its just a file object, why its base64?

Comment: I also tried without `"ContentEncoding": "base64"` , this is still the same.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You still haven't explained what exactly is `request.files["my_zip_file"]`? Is it a file object, is it bytes data, is it string base64, a file name? Please update the question with all the details and full code example.

Comment: `request.files["my_zip_file"]` is a file object uploaded via `multipart / form-data`